# Plot excess points on x axis in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, frequency

I am looking to plot data captured at 240 hz(x axis) vs data captured at 60hz(y axis). The x axis data is 4 times that of y axis and I would like 4 points on x axis to be plotted for 1 point on y axis, so that the result graph looks like a step.
My list: Y axis: `[0.0, 0.001, 0.003, 0,2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.88, 0.9, 1.0]`
 X Axis: `np.arange(1, 40) # numpy`

Any ideas how to club the 4 excess points into one in the graph?

Comment: Y has 11 points, X has 39 points in this case - were you just providing an example or this is your data? How should it be grouped then?

Comment: This is an actual data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.repeat` to duplicate each data point in your series as many times as you want. For your specific example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

X = np.arange(1,41)
Y = np.array([0.0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.88, 0.9, 1.0])
Y2 = np.repeat(Y,4)
print(Y2)

ax.plot(X,Y2)

plt.show()
```

Gives the following output for `Y2`:

```
[0.    0.    0.    0.    0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003
 0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
 0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.88  0.88  0.88  0.88  0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9
 1.    1.    1.    1.   ]
```

And the following figure:

[image: adding points to Y]

You can also do the opposite with

```
X2 = X[::4]
ax.plot(X2, Y)
```

In which case you get this figure:

[image: removing points from X]